# How to find the Active Accounts per Month since Jan 2016

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the below:
account_id, start_date, end_date

For every month since January 2016, I want to count the number of accounts that are active. If I have account A with start: '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and end: '2017-12-31 00:00:00' that account would be considered active for all months of 2017.
Any ideas how i can calculate that with postgresql?

Comment: The number of accounts active in a month is ambiguous.  Do you mean active on the first day?  Active on any day?  Active on the last day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the months using `generate_series()` and then use `left join` and aggregation.  The following counts accounts active on the first day of the month:

```
select gs.mon, count(a.start_date) as num_active
from generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, date_trunc('month', now()), interval '1 month') gs(mon) left join
     accounts a
     on a.start_date <= gs.mon  and
        (a.end_date >= gs.mon or a.end_date is null)
group by gs.mon;
```